# Download counter for skydrive shared files in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

I have attached some skydrive files in my Wordpress posts. I want to show how many times these were downloaded. Is there any plugin or theme customization or trick to do this easily and effectively? Is there any other service like skydrive (believe only google, microsoft and yahoo, nothing else) to do this job easily?

Comment: *@brz dot net:* How have you *"attached"* them? Can you link to an example?

Comment: There is specific embedded link for uploaded document in skydrive. I copy paste code in the wordpress post. It shows the file and user can download from skydrive shared folder

Comment: There seems to be no API for SkyDrive, so unless you know how to get the download count from them, there is no way to put it in a WordPress plugin. Maybe you should check [the Web Apps site](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) for a hosting service with a simple API to access this data, and then come back and ask how to do this from WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin should do the trick: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/

It'll allow you to set up a special "link" for everything to d/l and show numbers on the back-end.